# Randomization within different sized subgroups

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to assign half of each subgroup to a treatment condition and half to a control group.  When my subgroups have an odd number of records, the last one can be arbitrarily assigned.

I'm trying to do this within dplyr groups and struggling to account for odd/even.  I tried this:

```
set.seed(1)
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(group = case_when(
    n() %% 2 == 0 ~  sample(rep(c("treatment", "control"), n() / 2)),
    TRUE ~ sample(rep(c("treatment", "control"), ceiling(n() / 2)))[-1]
  ))
```

But I get the error:

> Error: `TRUE ~ sample(rep(c("treatment", "control"), ceiling(n()/2)))[-1]` must be length 10 or one, not 11

I'm also open to using `purrr` if that approach is more straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(group = sample(rep(c("treatment", "control"), ceiling(n()/2)), n()))
```

- For even number `n = 2k` of rows in a group, it shuffles `k` "treatment" and `k` "control" values.
- For odd number `n = 2k + 1`, it samples `2k + 1` values from `k + 1` "treatment" and `k + 1` "control" values. I believe this is what you need.

This of course can be generalized to any number of groups:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(group = sample(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), ceiling(n()/3)), n())) %>% 
  count(cyl, group)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Hadn't occurred to me to call `ceiling` in the even cases.

Comment: Remember to set a seed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does what the question asks for.

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(i = row_number() %in% sample(row_number(), n() %/% 2),
         group = ifelse(i, "treatment", "control")) %>%
  select(-i)
```

Check the results by `count`ing the `group` values.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(i = row_number() %in% sample(row_number(), n() %/% 2),
         group = ifelse(i, "treatment", "control")) %>%
  select(-i) %>%
  count(cyl, group)
## A tibble: 6 x 3
## Groups:   cyl [3]
#    cyl group         n
#  <dbl> <chr>     <int>
#1     4 control       6
#2     4 treatment     5
#3     6 control       4
#4     6 treatment     3
#5     8 control       7
#6     8 treatment     7
```